# Android bitmap allocation weirdness

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory

I'm having some trouble understanding why this code

```
public class BitmapAllocTest extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        byte[] b = new byte[20 * 1000 * 1000];
        b = null;
        Bitmap.createBitmap(2500, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    }
}
```

throws an OutOfMemory exception on a device with a 24mb heap limit. If I comment out either of the allocations it runs fine. I was under the impression that the java vm would try to garbage collect before throwing OutOfMemory exceptions.

I suspect it having to do with android allocating the bitmaps on the native heap.

Answer (score 1):

I posted this on the issue tracker and got this answer:

> There are a couple of things going on.
>
> The VM on older devices uses
>   conservative collection.  Most (but
>   not all) devices running >= 2.0 will
>   use type-precise GC, but none of them
>   yet have live-precise GC.
>
> What this means is, the fact that you
>   set "b = null" doesn't guarantee that
>   all copies of that reference are gone
>   -- a copy might still be sitting in a register somewhere, and without
>   liveness detection the GC can't know
>   that it will never be used again. 
>   It's also perfectly legal for the
>   compiler to discard the "b = null"
>   assignment since you never look at "b"
>   again.
>
> Bitmap pixel data uses the magical
>   "external allocation" mechanism rather
>   than the usual heap allocator. 
>   Sometimes you get unpleasant
>   interactions.
>
> We're working on fixing all of these
>   issues.

Link: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10821

Answer (score 0):

> I was under the impression that the java vm would try to garbage collect before throwing OutOfMemory exceptions.

You have to trigger the GC by yourself and retry. I had to do that recently and couldn't figure out another way to do that.

Comment: I tried your suggestion calling System.gc() before the bitmap allocation, also tried catching the error, calling gc() and then trying to allocate the bitmap again. I still get the OOM error though. :(

Comment: byte[] b = new byte[20 * 1000 * 1000];
b = null;
System.gc();
try {
Bitmap.createBitmap(2500, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
} catch(OutOfMemoryError e) {
System.gc();
Bitmap.createBitmap(2500, 2000, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
}

Comment: hm... well I have multiple bitmaps and recycled each one before calling the GC, which is not possible in your case...
I guess nulling the array isn't enough for the GC to grep it. only a guess